# Is it possible to open a folder browser dialog in Word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word

In my application, we have a requirement like opening a folder browser dialog on clicking an icon in the word document, and the user will be allowed to add some attachments through that. The word document we generate is a XML based word document and is opened through `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass`.Is it possible to open a folder browser dialog?

Can we handle this with any event of the document? Any suggestions or inputs would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, just create an instance of OpenFileDialog class and use his ShowDialog method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx

Beware I had some problems in the past with this class if Thread Apartment model is MTA:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/96991/net-2-0-beta-2-mtathread-and-openfiledialog

Comment: Hi Oscar, thanks for your response. BUt I am looking for how to open it from the word document. An event to handle to handle that from the word Document. If I get an event I will create an instance for it and open it.

Comment: I though that you were using Visual Studio Tools for Office. Mostly because is the only way I can think to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Every functionality that can be made by user over GUI, can also be done through Automation. In order to attach a file to Word Document, you would use "Insert Object" (http://www.ehow.com/how_5877175_add-attachments-ms-word.html).

Here is the [Word Interop Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Maybe you can find your answer there.